# 2007 SharePoint Rotator Linking

Tags: workflow

Hello Fellow SharePointers...  I am trying to set up my image rotator that links from the main page to open up in a new window.  Right now the image or story will link to a page that I have to create.  If that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a custom rotator you wrote or purchased... That means you need to edit the code.

If the rotator is using an anchor tag you would need to add a target attribute as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">New Browser Window</a>
```

If javascript is used you would have to edit the target of the [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) command.

Notice **target="_blank"** is the key ingredient.

Comment: I understand about the target blank tag.  In the image rotator web part is says create page you would enter a title then the url for the page name. I use test for example  Then in the page layout box it come with Article page with image left or right or blank web part page.  I select black web part page.  I go to Edit Page then all the web parts are on the page Rollup Image, Page Content, Header web part, Byline ect so once I create that webpart the page creates a rotator page that shows image1 2 3 ect.  So How would images open up in a new window linking to an article or video on another site

Comment: So, I understood that when you add the final webpart it generates a rotator webpart.

If I understood you correctly this seems like javascript.

You need to get to the code which generates the rotator web part, specifically the links... There you can change the target to blank. It might be HTML or Javascript code which is used to open the new window. If its javascript you will find a click event with a Window.Open command.

hope that helps.